# Import CSV from API output to google

Tags: api, csv, google-apps-script, import, google-sheets-api

I have absolutly no idea of what I'm doing but I'm trying to import CSV data from API output into a google sheets.

The data I want to import are bookings data, aleady generated as a csv file and I simply need to import all the data the first time and then update it (no need to re-import all the datas from last year)

The API URL is:

> https://www.beds24.com/api/csv/getbookingscsv

I need however to enter my username and my password and if necessary a date range.

So in my head it would be:
One script for the year booking import

```
username    XXXXX
password    •••••
datefrom    
dateto
```

One script for the day booking import using the date range

```
username    XXXXX
password    •••••
datefrom    2019-09-29
dateto      2019-09-29
```

The first look I took using googlescript I found out that I would probably need something like this:

```
function importCSV() {
   var var bookings = beds24api.beds24GetBookings(prop_key, data_option);
   var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.beds24.com/api/csv/getbookingscsv");  
   var content = res.getContentText();
   var authentication = {
       'authentication' : {
         'username' : XXXXX,
         'password' : •••••
       };
   };
}
```

```
function beds24GetBookingsCSV(username, password, data_option){
    return beds24JsonApi('https://www.beds24.com/api/csv/getbookingscsv',username, password, data_option);
    };
    return {
        beds24GetBookings: beds24GetBookingsCSV,
    };
}
```

Lot of you gonna get bleding eyes from this code but if I could get some help acheiving this that would be awesome!

Comment: Your second function is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with beds24 nor do I wish to.  But if you look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) you will find an example of `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`.  I believe that you'll need to include your authentication data into the options object or include them as elements of the querystring portion of the url.  Look to see in beds 24 has a Google Apps Script example or possibly a Javascript example.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will take a look!

Comment: Took a look on beds24 API faq but I couldn't find any code to help me so far.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  String url = "https://www.beds24.com/api/csv/getbookingscsv";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        String params = "username=XXX&password=YYY";

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(params);
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
       
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```

```
# Function to get data from Beds24 API
getBeds24Data <-function(username = property_mgmt$username,
                         password = property_mgmt$password,
                         datefrom = "2019-01-01",
                         dateto = "2019-12-30"){
  url <- "https://www.beds24.com/api/csv/getbookingscsv"

  response <- httr::POST(url=url, body = list("username" = username,
                                              "password"=password,
                                              datefrom = datefrom,
                                              dateto = dateto))
  beds24Data <- httr::content(response,type='text/csv',col_names=T,col_types=NULL)
  return(beds24Data)
}
```

Comment: Didn7t try it. I need a google script and it seems to be java?